# How to change finder model in Authentication plugin in CakePHP

Tags: authentication, cakephp

In built-in CakePHP AuthComponent I can change dynamicaly `userModel` or `finder` in AppController.php, by:

```
$this->Auth->setConfig('authenticate.Form.finder', 'Custom');
```

But, in new Authentication plugin (https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/master/docs/Migration-from-the-AuthComponent.md#migrate-authcomponent-settings), I set `userModel` and `finder` inside Application.php.

Now, how change these variables in AppController.php?

Comment: You can't do that, authentication will have already been done at that point. I'd suggest that you explain why exactly you need to do that on controller level, then maybe someone can suggest a solution for the middleware level.

Comment: I used it for separate areas, for admin (Users) and for clients (Employers extends Users) with custom finder. It was based by route prefix. Now, of course I know in `getAuthenticationService` method I can check prefix by `ServerRequestInterface $request` argument. But I moved each settings about Authentication to separate plugin, exactly to `Plugin.php` file.

Comment: That kinda sounds like authorization to me, ie allowing/denying access to a resource based on the identified users roles/capabilities. Authorization has intentionally not been included in the authentication plugin, as that is a separate concern, and is covered by the authorization plugin. Maybe you just need to get rid of the thought that this is a job for the authentication layer? But it really depends... what exactly do you mean when you say "_settings about Authentication_", and where in the `Plugin` classes do these settings live, and how are they connected with your app controller?

Comment: We run from the subject... There is option to change `userModel` and `finder` method from AppController?

Comment: I'm just trying to help you finding a solution for the underlying problem that you're trying to solve. As stated in my first comment, it's not possible, authentication happens in the middleware layer, there's nothing you can do in the controller layer, it's too late.